# VBA : Range method not giving desired output

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select a particular column's values using this code

```
Set rng = Range("O2", Range("O2").End(xlDown))
```

But somehow this is not working, I even tried using

```
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sample").Range("O2", Range("O2").End(xlDown))
```

which doesn't either.

Comment: How doesn't it works for you ? Any error ? It worked fine for me. use `Debug.Print Rng.Address` to check the range address. What's the desired output ?

Comment: Desired output is $O$2:$O$172315 but Debug.Print gives $O$2:$O$1048576

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine and will give you desired results if there are no blank cells in the column otherwise it will give you the wrong address

You can do the same thing like this

```
Dim frow As Long
frow = Worksheets("Sample").Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Worksheets("Sample").Range("O2:O" & frow)
Debug.Print rng.Address
```

Comment: This worked, but I am confused why     Set rng = Range("O2", Range("O2").End(xlDown)) didn't work.

Comment: Inconsistent data in that column I guess. Or you are not reffering to right worksheet range.

Answer (score 1):

> This worked, but I am confused why Set rng = Range("O2", Range("O2").End(xlDown)) didn't work

Were the cells below `O2` all blank, or were there hidden rows?

Using `Find` is more robust than the `xlUp` and `xlDown` techniques. It does deal with the issues I raise above (hidden rows etc)

```
Sub AnotherWay()
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("O:O").Find("*", [o1], xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
If rng1.Row > 2 Then
    Set rng2 = Range(rng1, [o2])
    Debug.Print rng2.Address
Else
    MsgBox "range invalid"
End If
End Sub
```